# Find, Replace and Save Regular expression in Unix Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a requirement where I have to do something like:

```
<string name="XYZ">Find And Replace This</string>
```

I should be able to change this to

```
<string name="XYZ">main.findAndReplaceThis</string>
```

And also I have to write the replaced value (`Find And Replace This`) in a separate file.

I am trying to do it using unix shell script but unable to do it. Can anyone please help?

Comment: what is the pattern here? Just `Find And Replace This` or whatever within `<string>` tags? Give more explanations so that the answer can be broad enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet here are people who can give you more efficient code, but here is basically what you want using the awk command:

```
#!/bin/bash

mystring="<string name=\"XYZ\">Find And Replace This</string>"

value=`echo $mystring | awk -F'>' '{print $2}' | awk -F'<' '{print $1}'`

functionname="main.`echo ${value//[[:blank:]]/}`"

mystring=`echo $mystring | awk -F'>' '{print $1}'`
mystring="${mystring}>${functionname}</string>"

echo "Value: ${value}"
echo "Mystring: ${mystring}"
```

Output:

```
Value: Find And Replace This
Mystring: <string name="XYZ">main.FindAndReplaceThis</string>
```